# how to call expressjs endpoint from static html file in vercel

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vercel

i have a very simple app with 1 `/api/index.js` server and 1 `index.html` file at the root.

`index.js` has a route `app.get("/api/mystuff", () => {...})`

`index.html` calls pings this route from a `<script>` with:

`const result = await fetch("/api/mystuff")`

all of this works locally, but when deployed to Vercel i get hit with a 404 from my request. the endpoint it's hitting is `https://myvercelapp.vercel.app/api/mystuff` and i'm getting a `The page could not be found NOT_FOUND` error. I don't know how to get this working, can someone steer me in the right direction?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the used tags I'm understanding you are using express with node.js.

Without seeing any of your code, I am guessing either your vercel.json isn't setup correctly (the guide explains this) or your index.js isn't setup correctly.

---

### Vercel Guide on using Express

In that case, Vercel has a great guide on [Using Express.js with Vercel](https://vercel.com/guides/using-express-with-vercel).

In vercel's guide they have a section addressing using [Standalone Express](https://vercel.com/guides/using-express-with-vercel#standalone-express).

In this guide they use an `index.js` **inside** of an `api` folder.

The index.js file:

```js
const app = require('express')();
const { v4 } = require('uuid');

app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
  const path = `/api/item/${v4()}`;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
  res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 's-max-age=1, stale-while-revalidate');
  res.end(`Hello! Go to item: <a href="${path}">${path}</a>`);
});

app.get('/api/item/:slug', (req, res) => {
  const { slug } = req.params;
  res.end(`Item: ${slug}`);
});

module.exports = app;
```

and the vercel.json which is what makes the whole project work.

```json
{
  "rewrites": [{ "source": "/api/(.*)", "destination": "/api" }]
}
```

And finally, [Adding a Public Directory](https://vercel.com/guides/using-express-with-vercel#adding-a-public-directory) which may explain more on how you can properly use Vercel with Express.

---

### The Problem

**The reason I assume that it's the `vercel.json` is the problem is due it working locally and not on Vercel. A good way to test this locally is using [vercel dev](https://vercel.com/docs/cli#commands/dev).**

---

### Working Example

I've created a public example which may help you. Please check https://github.com/Crispy-Cream/vercel-with-express for the source code example

and the public website https://vercel-with-express.vercel.app/api